# ?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless not working

Tags: android, layout, view

I am trying to implement a view which uses the default itemBackground style of Android (but with the oval background, that is used on action bar items etc). Somehow the following view is not showing the background at all. If I change android:background to android:foreground it only shows the rectangle but not the oval. Has anyone an idea how to fix that?

```
<LinearLayout
    app:visibleGone="@{showProfile}"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

       <ImageView
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> profileCallback.onClick()}"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 40):

Your code is correct, but the tricky thing is the parent layout needs a background too.

Try to set `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` or any other background to its parent. In your case it's the LinearLayout.

Comment: Love you --{--{@

Answer (score 8):

That line is not quite right. Use:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```

Comment: I was getting an `android.view.InflateException` when using `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` (which I already used in another projects and worked fine). When I set the background with your answer it worked! Thank you! FWIW: My app theme is `android:Theme.Material` (old projects was `Theme.AppCompat[...]`

Comment: InflateException on KitKat

Comment: Note that this can only be used from API 21 .

Answer (score 3):

If you have API 21 and above, you could try `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` instead.

However, in some cases (such as somehow being inside ConstraintLayout, whether directly or not), this is a known issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111819099

An example of a workaround is to use FrameLayout instead, just for the clicking effect. Here:

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/button" ...
            android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" .../>
        </FrameLayout>
```

If you have API 21+, You could at least set the foregroundTint too, to change the color of this effect.

Comment: Still it is showing the ripple effect till frame layout background only. In my case I need the ripple effect to be flow out of the boundary

Comment: @KingofMasses Did you try to set `clipChildren="false"` and `clipToPadding="false"` on the parent view/s ?

Comment: Yeah, but still it is showing around my frame layout only. I.e If i tried the same ?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless on list item for recycler view  it showing as I expected. But don't know why it is not working on Framelayout

Comment: @KingofMasses Try to make a POC. Many times I find out the reason via a tiny project instead of trying on the original one.

Comment: Ok sure, vll try that and let you know. Thanks

Comment: For me what worked was to set `clipChildren="false"`, `clipToPadding="false"` and `android:background="<some-bg>"` on all parent views.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar bug, may be it help someone:

If your parent is **FrameLayout** and it has another children with background, them can overlay your **selectableItemBackgroundBorderless**

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was resolved when I made the view clickable. Either add android:clickable="true" or programmatically add a click listener on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

and

```
  `android:clipChildern="false"  
   android:clipToPadding="false"`
```

for ALL the parent layouts

Answer (score 0):

You should use **android:focusable** attribute in your ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="@{() -> profileCallback.onClick()}"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_image" />
```